# Why are the following SQL queries not equivalent?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT c.cname
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.age > ALL (SELECT c2.age
 FROM Customers c2
 WHERE c2.type = 'snowboard'); 

SELECT c.cname
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.age > (SELECT MAX(c2.age)
 FROM Customers c2
 WHERE c2.type = 'snowboard')
```

They look the same to me because MAX(c2.age) is greater or equal than all the values in the column ages and if c.age is greater than MAX(c2.age) then it's greater than all the values.

Comment: Please tag dbms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are no matches for `snowboard`, then the first returns all rows and the second returns none.

The logic for the first follows the colloquial definition of "all".  If there are no matches, then any value is greater than the (non-existent) value from the subquery.  Note:  this is even true of `NULL` (at least in SQL Server).

The second query returns `NULL` when there are no matches.  Basically, comparisons to `NULL` never return true -- well, there are a few exceptions.

Hint for the future:  if two queries look like they are the same, but don't return the same values, then one of two things is usually the culprit:

- `NULL` values is involved
- One of the tables is empty

Comment: Ohhhh lol, got it. I got that one wrong of the mid-term. I think that detecting the flaw of that question is very hard for students who have been studying SQL for 1 month.

Comment: To elaborate on your claim, any comparison to NULL returns the value UNKNOWN since SQL uses a three value logic.

Comment: @daniel . . . .That is correct.  Apparently, though, `NULL` is greater than a non-existent value.  Curious, because `NULL > NULL` evaluates to `NULL`.